# Inputs de pendiente de select

Tags: select, type

Buenas quiero hacer una consulta de mysql por medio de un select y la informcion de cada seleccion me la lleve inputs independientes "tengo la tabla pais y dentro de ella hay el Nombre_pais, Poblacion,monenda ydioma", quiero que cuando seleccione españa, me muestre todo lo demas en input de type txt. gracias

Comment: Deberías mirar [cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tú pregunta sea mejor recibida y comprendida por la comunidad.

Comment: Agrega lo que has hecho, un codigo, una imagen, algo con lo que se te pueda ayudar porque así nada podemos hacer para solucionar tu problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo muy bien la pregunta porque no se en que ambiente estas desarrollando, pero aun así te voy a dar unos consejos. Si estas trabajando en html, puedes hacer una función en javascript para que de forma asincrona busque la información que necesitas en la base de datos y mostrarla en pantalla, en el evento onchange pones tu función.

Esta podría ser una solución a tu problema, debes repasar un poco html y javascript para entender el comportamiento de esta clase de peticiones, y también hay que ordenar bien el código para que sea entendible.

```
    <?php 
//Esta sentencia habilita que php muestre o no los errores
ini_set("display_errors","Off");
require ('conexion.php'); 
$query = "SELECT id_pais,nombre,poblacion,idioma FROM pais ORDER BY id_pais"; 
$resultado=$mysqli->query($query); 
if (!(empty($_POST))){
    $sql="select * from pais where id_pais='{$_POST['cbx_pais']}' limit 1";
    $pais_sel=$mysqli->query($sql)->fetch_assoc(); 
}
?> 
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight">
    <tr>
        <td> 
            <div>Eje programatico : 
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" id="frmpais" name="frmpais">
                    <select name="cbx_pais" id="cbx_pais" onchange='document.getElementById("frmpais").submit();'> 
                    <option value="0">Seleccionar pais</option> 
                        <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?> 
                            <option value="<?php echo $row['id_pais']; ?>" <?php echo (($row['id_pais']==$_POST['cbx_pais'])?'selected':''); ?>>
                                <?php echo $row['nombre']; ?>
                            </option> 
                        <?php } ?> 
                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  
<div style="margin:5px;">
    POBLACION <input type='text' id='poblacion' value="<?php echo $pais_sel['poblacion']; ?>" /> <br> 
    IDIONA<input type='text' id='idioma' value="<?php echo $pais_sel['idioma']; ?>" />
</div>
```

Comment: que pena, lo que pasa es que tengo un trabajo del colegio y esta pidiendo que desde php se haga esa consulta y no se como

Comment: Si quieres hacer la consulta en php entonces el select es html. Para ofrecerte una propuesta de código necesito que me indiques si estas programando php embebido (dentro del html) u otra forma de programación en php (Ejm. POO, MVC o un Framework como Laravel o PHPCake o Codeigniter). Si colocas el código de lo que llevas hecho es más fácil o si no tienes ni idea de por donde empezar yo te digo.

Comment: Amigo esto es lo que tengo

Comment: <?php
 require ('conexion.php');
 $query = "SELECT id_pais,nombre,poblacion,idioma FROM pais ORDER BY id_pais";
 $resultado=$mysqli->query($query);
?>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight"><tr><td>
   <div>Eje programatico : 
   <select name="cbx_pais" id="cbx_pais" onchange='cambioOpciones();'>
    <option value="0">Seleccionar pais</option>
    <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['id_pais']; ?>"><?php echo $row['nombre'];....

Comment: ... ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                           </select></div>
            <br> POBLACION <input type='text' id='solucion' />
            <br> IDIONA<input type='text' id='material' />

Comment: este, codigo, me muestra todos los paises del select, me falta es que me cargue la informacion en los input

Comment: Tienes la mitad del ejercicio, te sugiero usar un formulario sobre la misma página de esta forma tendrás todas las opciones. Ya te paso una solución en código

Comment: Hola @fredycardona, te recomiendo como lectura obligatoria [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). De igual modo, te sugiero que el código que adjuntas como comentario a la respuesta ofrecida lo incluyas en tu pregunta. Para ello, edita tu pregunta e incluye el código que tienes, para que de esta forma, tenga el formato correcto visible para todos. Saludos